# Showing MDI form as modal

Tags: delphi, mdi

This will sound against the nature of MDI.. I need to show a MDI form (FormStyle=fsMdiChild) as modal sometimes. And I also need to access the part between Application.CreateForm and OnShow event of another MDI form, i.e.

```
Application.CreateForm(Form2,TForm2); // but don't set form2's visible property true.
Form2.caption:='not working example'; 
Form2.SomeMagicToSetVisibleTrue;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first problem: Add another constructor, for example CreateAsMDI, like this:

```
constructor TModalAndMDIForm.CreateAsMDI(AOwner: TComponent); 
begin 
  f_blChild := true; 
  GlobalNameSpace.BeginWrite; 
  try 
    inherited CreateNew(AOwner); 
    if(not(csDesigning in ComponentState)) then begin 
      Include(FFormState, fsCreating); 
      try 
        FormStyle := fsMDIChild; 
        if(not(InitInheritedComponent(self, TForm))) then 
          raise Exception.CreateFmt('Can't create %s as MDI child', [ClassName]); 
      finally 
        Exclude(FFormState, fsCreating); 
      end; 
    end; 
  finally 
    GlobalNameSpace.EndWrite; 
  end; 
end;
```

In the normal constructor just set the variable f_blChild to false and call the inherited create.

You need two more things, rather self explaining:

```
procedure TModalAndMDIForm.Loaded; 
begin 
  inherited; 
  if(f_blChild) then 
    Position := poDefault 
  else begin 
    Position := poOwnerFormCenter; 
    BorderStyle := bsDialog; 
  end; 
end; 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
procedure TModalAndMDIForm.DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction); 
begin 
  if(f_blChild) then 
    Action := caFree; 
  inherited DoClose(Action); 
end;
```

Now you can call the form modal, if created with the standard constructor, and as MDI child, if created with CreateAsMDI.

If you include this in your form's declaration

```
property IsChild: boolean read f_blChild;
```

you can even do things depending on whether the form is an MDI child or not, just interrogating the isChild property.

As for your second problem: do not use Application.CreateForm, but create your form yourself:

Here the two creations for modal and MDI:

```
//Modal 
frmDialog := TMyForm.Create(self); 
// Your Code
frmDialog.ShowModal; 
frmDialog.Release; 

//MDI-Child 
frmDialog := TMyForm.CreateChild(self); 
// Your code
frmDialog.Show;
```

I have translated this answer form an article on the site [DelphiPraxis](http://www.delphipraxis.net/topic73059.html).

Comment: (If you happen to use a form with `OldCreateOrder` set to `True`) you should add `if OldCreateOrder then DoCreate` at the end of `TModalAndMDIForm.CreateAsMDI`.

Comment: The link to the original code is broken. Here is a [modified working version](https://www.delphipraxis.net/61196-formular-als-mdi-child-und-modalen-dialog-nutzen.html).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to create a trivial subclass of the form, and set

*FormStyle = fsMDIChild*

**AND**

*Form.Visible = False*

in the property inspector. This is tried and tested!

Comment: There were Delphi versions were it wasn't possible to set this combination of properties in the property inspector. It works in Delphi 2009, but I don't know since which version. It's such a trivial thing to do though that I assumed the OP is using a Delphi version where that's not an option.

Comment: I think the project that I first done this on was in Delphi 6 at the time. From memory, the important thing is to set the properties in the correct order - unless I edited the DFM directly (too long ago to remember)

Answer (score 1):

At least for Delphi 2007 and 2009 creating the MDI child form invisible is easy. For the early Delphi versions (where it was impossible to set `Visible` to `False` in the property inspector) you just have to provide a handler for the `OnCreate` event and access a protected field of the class:

```
procedure TMDIChild.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFormState := FFormState - [fsVisible];
end;
```

This will disable the automatic showing of the MDI child. After you are done with your other initialisations you can simply `Show` it or set `Visible` to `True`.

I will not try to answer your question about modal MDI child forms, as this violates the conventions of the Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

No answers above actually does the job required. The best answer is wrong as well, because of following:

- Opening the first form;
- Maximize it;
- Now say this form calls another form (mdi);
- When it is constructed the same way you will get buggy layout... (it will mdi child, but not maximized, however the first will be still maximized). So a buggy state.

If you really need to decide in run-time whether it's a fsMDIChild or fsNormal you need to apply following approach.

1. You have form which is stored as fsNormal in design (or vice-versa);
2. Override the InitializeNewForm method;
3. Set the value of FFormStyle to fsMDIChild (as shown below).

...

```
TYourForm = class(TForm)
...
protected
  procedure InitializeNewForm; override;
...

procedure TYourForm.InitializeNewForm;
var
  FS: ^TFormStyle;
begin
  inherited;
  if DoYourCheckForMDI then
    begin
      FS := @FormStyle;
      FS^ := fsMDIChild;
    end;
end;
```